# XeLaTeX problem? Undefined control sequence.

Tags: xetex, errors, document-classes

I'm new to LaTeX.

I downloaded a template for making a CV.

[here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv)

It says to be compiled with biber and XeLaTeX

Im trying with `xelatex vc_10.tex` but always getting errors, fixed them by searching the web but with this one I'm completely stuck.

Can anyone help with this one?

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx) (./cv_10.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
\um_set_mathsymbol:nNNn #1#2#3#4->\tl_case:Nnn 
                                               #3{\mathop {\um_set_big_opera...
l.27 \begin{document}
```

these are the first lines of the file

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv} % Add 'print' as an option into the square bracket to remove colors from this template for printing

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include publications

\begin{document}
```

and gives the error on the `\begin{document}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: This is a LaTeX3 macro. Do you have those LaTeX3 packages installed?

Comment: Which packages? I did `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex3`

Comment: \tl_case:Nnn is a rather new command. So probably your latex3 packages are outdated.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer More precisely, they are mismatched: the version of `unicode-math` installed must be newer than the version of `expl3`.

Comment: @JosephWright I installed it from https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math today. What else could it be?

Comment: I can compile it with MikTeX 2.9 and the appropriate packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion it's a flaw to install TeX Live via any Unix package manager. Normally they only provide an outdated version of TeX Live. I guess you version is TeX Live 2009.

The current newest version is TeX Live 2013. So I recommend to install TeX Live 2013 and everything will work fine.

- http://www.tug.org/texlive/
- [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

There a a lot of other related question too.