# Undefined control sequence on fresh "vanilla" TeXLive on Windows

Tags: xetex, texlive

I reinstalled Windows today, then installed "vanilla" TeXLive 2015 using `install-tl-windows.exe`. I did everything as I already did before: installed TeXLive with the `small-scheme` and then installed few other packages I use. But when I try to build the document I was able to build just few hours ago (before I reinstalled Windows) I get the following error message:

> ```
>  81.
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \um_set_mathsymbol:nNNn #1#2#3#4->\tl_case:Nnn 
>                                                #3{\mathop {\um_set_big_opera...
> l.81 \setmathfont{[Asana-Math]}
> ```

The only thing I found so far is [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115968/xelatex-problem-undefined-control-sequence). But here it was suggested that the problem could be resolved by just switching to "vanilla" TeXLive which I already use. It is also mentioned that the actual reason is a mismatch in versions of `unicode-math` and `expl3` ( I guess it is called `l3experimental` nowadays).

But how can I tell if there is a mismatch? And how can I fix it?

Or do I simply have some package missing? If so which one?

Comment: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/303

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Can you give `\listfiles` output? (Just say `\listfiles` before your `\begin{document}` and copypasta that output into your question.)

Comment: There's a temporary issue to do with an update to `expl3`. The author of `unicode-math` is aware of it (he's on the team): for the moment do `\usepackage{expl3}\ExplSyntaxOn\cs_set_eq:NN\tl_case:Nnn\tl_case:NnF\cs_set_eq:NN\int_case:nnn\int_case:nnF\ExplSyntaxOff` before loading `unicode-math`.

Comment: I believe that this is fixed now. You should be able to update TeXLive 2015 to a working version. Please note http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258669/a-problem-with-unicode-math-sty-used-in-a-cls-file

Comment: @Andy, you're right. It works now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a temporary problem, fixed by update to expl3.