# A problem with unicode-math.sty used in a .cls file

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I am having a problem with the `unicode-math.sty` (I'm using MacTeX2015, 
*updated this morning*). I am using the following MWE class file.

#### `testthis.cls`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2001/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{testthis}[2015/08/04 v1.0 TESTTHIS Author Class]

\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{LucidaBrightOT}
\setmathfont{LucidaBrightMathOT}

%\makeatletter

\newcommand{\m@keit}{blablabla}

\endinput
```

When I compile the following file with XeLaTeX:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{testthis}

\begin{document}

A test.

\end{document}
```

I get this error:

> ./testthis.cls:13: LaTeX Error: Command \m already defined.
>                  Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>       Type  H   for immediate help.
>       ...
>
> l.13 \newcommand{\m@keit}{blablabla}

It would appear that `\setmathfont` is causing `@` to revert to 'other': If I **either** uncomment `\makeatletter` **or** run the TeX file with TeXLive 2014 or earlier, the error goes away. Alternatively, if I comment-out `\setmathfont{LucidaBrightMathOT}` the error also goes away.

A puzzle and any insights would be most welcome.

Comment: Actually, the question is pertinent: To the best of my knowledge, this worked correctly yesterday, before I did an update to TeXLive. Thus the italics...

Comment: For some reasons, the category code of `@` is changed to 12 after `\setmathfont` is processed. Investigating over the bug.

Comment: See https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/309

Comment: For the time being, I use `\AtBeginDocument{\setmathfont{...}}` which works as a workaround in my case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was caused by a now-fixed bug in the package.